# What does this sentence mean? I don't understand "only ever" here

Tags: word-usage

Dear friends who I normally only ever get completely leathered with,

Comment: I read this page: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301979/usage-of-only-ever                                and I guess I'm confused between the two meaning: "I only drink with these friends and no one else or I rarely drink with them" can anyone tell me how I can understand only ever's right meaning in every sentence?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are friends who you only ever see when you get drunk with them.

An example would be some rugby drinking friends you only really see when you are out drinking and always end up getting drunk with.

The 'only ever' means that every single time you see each other you end up drunk! Although I'm assuming it is being used in the greeting to exaggerated effect. :-)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I agree with you Good JuJu.

Comment: Thanks.. I don't know who downvoted my answer.  I speak from experience and have probably started the same sentence using the same opening line in the past! :-)

Answer (score -2):

*Only ever* here means *rare*
The speaker intends to tell that with these friends I very rarely get completely drunk. May be he just got leathered once with them or may be never.